# Persisting Collection<T> using Objectify4 on GAE

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have been having issues with persisting a generic Collection on Google datastore using Objectify4. E.g.

```
@Entity
class AnimalInfo
{
  @Id
  String id;
  Collection<Animal> animals;
}

@EntitySubClass
class Cat extends Animal
{
  String name;
}

@EntitySubClass
class Dog extends Animal
{
  String name;
}

@Entity
class Animal
{
  @Id
  String id;
}
```

How can I persist the AnimalInfo class and retrieve it again. I have tried:
`objectify.save().entities(animalInfo).now();` but while fetching it back again: `objectify.load().type(AnimalInfo.class).id(animalInfo.id).get();` doesnt have the `name` field corresponding to the extended class Cat or Dog.

This is also probably logical because Animal class doesnt have a field `name`. But how do I get this to work? A generic interface IAnimal (in place of Animal class) is a better solution design-wise, but that doesnt work with Objectify as it needs concrete types.

Any solution for the above problem??

---

Thanks in advance.

Shaun

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, it looks like you want a collection of references to polymorphic entities.  Do this:

```
@Entity
class AnimalInfo {
  @Id String id;
  Collection<Ref<Animal>> animals = new ArrayList<Ref<Animal>>();
}
```

You need Refs to create the reference to the other entities. You could use Key too, but it will be less convenient.  You may also want to look into the `@Load` annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This means that `animals` collection will only have references to the datastore. How do I also have in-memory instances of Animal within it (without persisting it)? I can think of a workaround by having a second Collection just to have in-memory `Animals` and update the Ref collection whenever the regular collection is updated? I dont think it is a good solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Objectify does not currently support polymorphism in @ Embed objects. If you want a crude solution that works right now, you can use @ Serialize.